# Chart.js v2: space between doughnut inside doughnut

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js2

I am using chart.js v2.5.0.
I put doughnut inside doughnut.

I want the disdance between 2 doughnuts(**A**) to be larger without affecting the distance between slices inside the same doughnut(**B**).

Please see the following image:

[image: Picture 1]

Currently I am using the property **borderWidth**.
However, this also affects the width of **B**.

Please see the following code:

```
options: {
                elements: {
                    arc: {
                        borderWidth: 18,
                    },
                },
                cutoutPercentage: 60,
                responsive: true,
            }
```

I want the doughnuts to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is to extend the existing `doughnut` controller and overwrite the `update` method with your own logic for determining the spacing.

Here is an example demonstrating how you would do this.  With this implementation, I added a new doughnut chart option property called `datasetRadiusBuffer` that controls the white space between each dataset.

```
var helpers = Chart.helpers;

// this option will control the white space between embedded charts when there is more than 1 dataset
helpers.extend(Chart.defaults.doughnut, {
  datasetRadiusBuffer: 0
});

Chart.controllers.doughnut = Chart.controllers.doughnut.extend({
  update: function(reset) {
    var me = this;
    var chart = me.chart,
        chartArea = chart.chartArea,
        opts = chart.options,
        arcOpts = opts.elements.arc,
        availableWidth = chartArea.right - chartArea.left - arcOpts.borderWidth,
        availableHeight = chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top - arcOpts.borderWidth,
        minSize = Math.min(availableWidth, availableHeight),
        offset = {
          x: 0,
          y: 0
        },
        meta = me.getMeta(),
        cutoutPercentage = opts.cutoutPercentage,
        circumference = opts.circumference;

    // If the chart's circumference isn't a full circle, calculate minSize as a ratio of the width/height of the arc
    if (circumference < Math.PI * 2.0) {
      var startAngle = opts.rotation % (Math.PI * 2.0);
      startAngle += Math.PI * 2.0 * (startAngle >= Math.PI ? -1 : startAngle < -Math.PI ? 1 : 0);
      var endAngle = startAngle + circumference;
      var start = {x: Math.cos(startAngle), y: Math.sin(startAngle)};
      var end = {x: Math.cos(endAngle), y: Math.sin(endAngle)};
      var contains0 = (startAngle <= 0 && 0 <= endAngle) || (startAngle <= Math.PI * 2.0 && Math.PI * 2.0 <= endAngle);
      var contains90 = (startAngle <= Math.PI * 0.5 && Math.PI * 0.5 <= endAngle) || (startAngle <= Math.PI * 2.5 && Math.PI * 2.5 <= endAngle);
      var contains180 = (startAngle <= -Math.PI && -Math.PI <= endAngle) || (startAngle <= Math.PI && Math.PI <= endAngle);
      var contains270 = (startAngle <= -Math.PI * 0.5 && -Math.PI * 0.5 <= endAngle) || (startAngle <= Math.PI * 1.5 && Math.PI * 1.5 <= endAngle);
      var cutout = cutoutPercentage / 100.0;
      var min = {x: contains180 ? -1 : Math.min(start.x * (start.x < 0 ? 1 : cutout), end.x * (end.x < 0 ? 1 : cutout)), y: contains270 ? -1 : Math.min(start.y * (start.y < 0 ? 1 : cutout), end.y * (end.y < 0 ? 1 : cutout))};
      var max = {x: contains0 ? 1 : Math.max(start.x * (start.x > 0 ? 1 : cutout), end.x * (end.x > 0 ? 1 : cutout)), y: contains90 ? 1 : Math.max(start.y * (start.y > 0 ? 1 : cutout), end.y * (end.y > 0 ? 1 : cutout))};
      var size = {width: (max.x - min.x) * 0.5, height: (max.y - min.y) * 0.5};
      minSize = Math.min(availableWidth / size.width, availableHeight / size.height);
      offset = {x: (max.x + min.x) * -0.5, y: (max.y + min.y) * -0.5};
    }

    chart.borderWidth = me.getMaxBorderWidth(meta.data);
    chart.outerRadius = Math.max((minSize - chart.borderWidth) / 2, 0);
    chart.innerRadius = Math.max(cutoutPercentage ? (chart.outerRadius / 100) * (cutoutPercentage) : 0, 0);
    chart.radiusLength = ((chart.outerRadius - chart.innerRadius) / chart.getVisibleDatasetCount()) + 25;
    chart.offsetX = offset.x * chart.outerRadius;
    chart.offsetY = offset.y * chart.outerRadius;

    meta.total = me.calculateTotal();

    me.outerRadius = chart.outerRadius - (chart.radiusLength * me.getRingIndex(me.index));
    me.innerRadius = Math.max(me.outerRadius - chart.radiusLength, 0);

    // factor in the radius buffer if the chart has more than 1 dataset
    if (me.index > 0) {
      me.outerRadius -= opts.datasetRadiusBuffer;
      me.innerRadius -= opts.datasetRadiusBuffer;
    }

    helpers.each(meta.data, function(arc, index) {
      me.updateElement(arc, index, reset);
    });
  },
});
```

You can see a live example at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/GWeLXm).

Answer (score 0):

To make it work with the latest ChartJS 2.7.2, I've just copied the source as suggested from https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/controllers/controller.doughnut.js. Then I added the patch:

```
if (me.index > 0) {
  me.outerRadius -= opts.datasetRadiusBuffer;
  me.innerRadius -= opts.datasetRadiusBuffer;
}
```

Everything was working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

[Picture of 3 datasets in doughnut chart with "padding"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0Jak.png)

I achieved this by inserting a transparent dataset between the colored datasets. Didn't find another "easy" way.

In the end it was easier to do the whole chart myself instead of using chartjs.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution here : [Padding Between Pie Charts in chart js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60194027/padding-between-pie-charts-in-chart-js)

```js
const colors = ["#FF6384", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56"];
var pieChart = new Chart("myChart", {
     type: 'pie',
     data: {
           labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"],
          datasets: [{      
                   data: [8, 5, 6],
                   backgroundColor: colors,
     },{ 
     weight: 0.2
     },{ 
     data: [5, 7, 4],
     backgroundColor: colors,
     weight: 1.2
     }]
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```