# Chart.js v2: make outside doughnut thicker

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js2

I am using chart.js v2.5.0.
I put doughnut inside doughnut.

I want to make the outside doughnut thicker than the inside doughnuts.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: where your code ?

Comment: It's just generic code. Sample here: [link](https://codepen.io/DUKEiLL/pen/ZKLozg)

Comment: like this way https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmRLRx

Comment: This solution also affect on the space between values. I need that will affect only the space between datasets.

Comment: @DUKEiLL This answer might help counteract that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43212372/4660897