# Chart.js How to make more space between doughnut inside doughnut?

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

Is there any way to make some more space between doughnut chart inside of doughnut chart?
Currently it looks like this:
[image]

And I want it to look like this: (more space between doughnuts)
[image]

Comment: No option exists natively in chart.js: there was a solution extending doughnut controller (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202276/chart-js-v2-space-between-doughnut-inside-doughnut) but it's not working with current chart.js version (2.7.1)

Comment: yes i  have seen this solution but sadly it doesn't work anymore

Comment: You can try to update that extension to current version

Comment: @ChrisK. did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not working anymore:

[Chart.js v2: space between doughnut inside doughnut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202276/chart-js-v2-space-between-doughnut-inside-doughnut)

but i found another one that works just adding empty data between

[Padding Between Pie Charts in chart js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60194027/padding-between-pie-charts-in-chart-js)

```
const colors = ["#FF6384", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56"];
var pieChart = new Chart("myChart", {
   type: 'pie',
   data: {
     labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"],
     datasets: [{      
        data: [8, 5, 6],
      backgroundColor: colors,
  },{ 
  weight: 0.2
  },{ 
  data: [5, 7, 4],
  backgroundColor: colors,
  weight: 1.2
}]}})
```