# Padding Between Pie Charts in chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am working on a project using chart.js for work and I need to know if there is a way to add some space between datasets of a pie chart.

What I have so far is in the chart depicted below, and I want there to be some padding between the inner and outer datasets.

I have tried setting one of the charts to a *doughnut* type or adding a thicker outer border on the inner chart, and neither of those are what I needed.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain the desired result by adding an empty dataset between the two existing ones and defining a [`weight`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#styling) property on the empty and the inner dataset.

```js
const colors = ["#FF6384", "#36A2EB", "#FFCE56"];
var pieChart = new Chart("myChart", {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow"],
    datasets: [{      
      data: [8, 5, 6],
      backgroundColor: colors,
    }, 
    { 
      weight: 0.2
    },
    { 
      data: [5, 7, 4],
      backgroundColor: colors,
      weight: 1.2
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is fantastic. It's exactly what I was looking for